# Express $\zeta(n)$, in particular the Apéry's constant, in terms of series involving Gregory coefficients or the Schröder's integral

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, integration, riemann-zeta-function

The idea and motivation of this post is to know if it is possible to express integer arguments of the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(n)$, in particular $\zeta(3)$, in terms of series involving the so-called Gregory coefficients or the so-called Schröder's integral formula. Having these identities that I evoke, as a relationships for the integer arguments of the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(n)$ the best mathematical content.

Gregory coefficients are an interesting sequence. See if you need it the Wikipedia article for [*Gregory coefficients.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregory_coefficients) In my aproach I didn't exploit the asymptotic, or other elements as recurrence formulas.

> **Question.** My attempts are showed in next examples, as I've said I would to know if it is possible to state formulas similar than mine, with the best mathematical content or interesting in themselves. I don't know if my approach and elaboration is satisfactory (my strategy was exploit well known integral representations for $\zeta(3)$ and try make more calculations hoping to find sometthing more interesting). What is your appoach to get relationships for $\zeta(3)$, or $\zeta(n)$, and Gregory coefficients $G_n$ (integral representation ofr Gregory coefficients or series involving Gregory coefficients)? **Many thanks.**

**Example 1.** Take the derivative of the generating function of Gregory coefficients, after we multiply by $(\log z)^r$ and integrating over the unit interval with the purpose to exploit the formula cited by Janous in [1] in the last paragraph of the proof of his **Theorem 2.1** (he cited it as [2]), we get 
$$-(1)^r r!=(-1)^r r!\zeta(r+1)-\sum_{n=1}^\infty|G_n|\int_0^1 z^n\left(\frac{n\log(1-z)}{z}-\frac{1}{1-z}\right)dz.$$

**Example 2.** A more elaborated example is write the generating function for the Gregory coefficients as $$-1=\frac{\log(1-z)}{z}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty|G_n|\log(1-z)z^{n-1},$$
after we multiply by $\log z$ and integrating over the unit interval exploiting  Beukers integrals ([3]) we get

$$\zeta(3)=1-\sum_{n=1}^\infty|G_n|\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k}\int_0^1(\log z)z^{n+k-1}dz.$$
Finally after integrating we use the definition of the Hurwitz Lerch transcendent and Schröder's integral formula ([4]) I wrote previous identity as 
$$\zeta(3)=1+\int_0^\infty\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k}\Phi\left(\frac{1}{1+x},2,k+1\right)\right)\frac{dx}{(1+x)(\pi^2+\log^2 x)}.$$

**Example 3 (Similar than first example, we conclude that it is the same than previous example).** Similarly if there aren't mistakes, from the derivative of the generating function of the Gregory coefficients

$$-1=\frac{-1}{1-\omega}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty|G_n|\omega^n\left(\frac{n\log(1-\omega)}{\omega}-\frac{1}{1-\omega}\right),$$
for $|\omega|<1$, we make the specialization $\omega=xyz$, then integrating for the unit cube, exploiting the known integral representation for the Apéry's constant (see the first formula from this section of the Wikipedia [Apéry's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ap%C3%A9ry%27s_constant#Irrational_number)) we obtain

$$-1=-\zeta(3)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{n}{k}\frac{1}{(n+k)^3}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(n+k)^3}\right).$$
We observe that this identity is the same that the series showed in Example 2.

### References:

[1] Whalther Janous, *AROUND APÉRY’S CONSTANT*, Journal of Inequalities in Pure and Applied Mathematics, Volume 7, Issue 1, Article 35 (2006).

[2] S.R. Finch, *Mathematical Constants*, page 43, Cambridge University Press, Cambridge (2003).

[3] F. Beukers, *A Note on the Irrationality of* $\zeta(2)$ *and* $\zeta(3)$,  Bulletinf of the London Mathematical Society, 11 (3), 268–272 (1979).

[4] I. V. Blagouchine, *A Note on Some Recent Results for the Bernoulli Numbers of the Second Kind*, Journal of Integer Sequences, Vol. 20, No. 3 (2017).

or

E. Schröder, *Bestimmung des infinitären Werthes des Integrals* $\int_0^1 (u)_n du$, Z. Math. Phys., 25 (1880), 106–117.

Comment: My last attempt is to use the inverse function of the Gudermannian function to state $$\frac{7}{\pi^2}\zeta(3)=-\int_0^1\operatorname{gd}^{-1}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}z\right)\log(1-z)dz+\int_0^1\operatorname{gd}^{-1}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}z\right)\sum_{n=1}^\infty|G_n|\log(1-z)z^ndz,$$ but I do not know if this formula is interesting or calculate the integrals on the RHS.

Comment: Also it is possible to prove that $\zeta(3)+ \int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(x)}{\log(1-x)}dx$ is equal to $$\int_0^\infty\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^2}\Phi\left(\frac{1}{1+x},1,k+1\right)\right)\frac{dx}{(1+x)(\pi^2+\log^2 x)}.$$

Comment: Also that $\zeta(3)-\frac{23}{8}+\frac{\pi^2}{2}$ is equal to $$-\int_0^\infty\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k}\Phi\left(\frac{1}{1+x},3,k+2\right)\right)\frac{dx}{(1+x)(\pi^2+\log^2 x)}.$$

Comment: And for integers $k\geq 2$ one has 

$$-2^{-k}=k-\sum_{m=2}^{k}\zeta(m)+\int_0^\infty\left(\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{1}{m}\Phi\left(\frac{1}{1+x},k,m+2\right)\right)\frac{dx}{(1+x)(\pi^2+\log^2 x)}.$$